# c# Console.WriteLine();

Tags: c#, console.writeline, console.readline

In C#, after I write `Console.WriteLine()` and I'm asked to enter several values, can I get them all in one method? For example:

```
double a, b, c = 0;
Console.WriteLine("please enter the values of:\n a value:\n b value: \n c value:");
```

thanks for the help (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no BCL methods for this specific functionality, but you could use a helper function to collect these without too much repetition.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string RequestInput(string variableName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{variableName}:");
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("please enter the values of:");
    var a = double.Parse(RequestInput("a"));
    var b = double.Parse(RequestInput("b"));
    var c = double.Parse(RequestInput("c"));

}
```

Comment: This won't compile for me locally. The RequestInput method would need to be outside the Main method or be non-static.

Comment: This is called a static local function, it was added in C# 8, but I will downgrade to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following, which assumes that the user will enter a string in the console like `"2.3 3.4 4.5"`. You may need to do some checking to make sure the input is correct.

```
double  a = 0.0, b = 0.0, c = 0.0;
Console.WriteLine("please enter the values of: a b c");

string input = Console.ReadLine();
string[] inputParts = input.Split(' ');

if (inputParts.Length > 0 && inputParts[0] != null) 
{
    Double.TryParse(inputParts[0], out a);
}

if (inputParts.Length > 1 && inputParts[1] != null) 
{
    Double.TryParse(inputParts[1], out b);
}

if (inputParts.Length > 2 && inputParts[2] != null) 
{
    Double.TryParse(inputParts[2], out c);
}

Console.WriteLine($"a: {a.ToString()}");
Console.WriteLine($"b: {b.ToString()}");
Console.WriteLine($"c: {c.ToString()}");
```